# testng-users › how to mark test case as Not applicable in TestNG , Don't want to skip or ignore test case

Tags: testng

Is there any way to mark a test case as Not Applicable. I have a scenario where I want to run 20 test cases out of 100 and same time I want total count as 100 in the report. If I will mark other test cases as skip or ignore, that time total test case count will reflect as 20 in the report.

Comment: Please try using groups. https://www.guru99.com/introduction-testng-groups.html

Answer (score 0):

we can run test cases what we want. In output report we will get count of only no of test cases executed. If we run 20 then out will be 20 only.

see this https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you go about doing it

You should be able to build a custom report which basically retrieves the excluded tests (which are essentially tests that are disabled)

`iSuiteResult.getTestContext().getExcludedMethods()` <<--- This should give you the list of excluded methods which you can use to add up to get the total tests.

So you could do the following:

- Build a custom annotation that would be used to annotate the tests which indicates which feature would a test belong to.
- Build an IAnnotationTransformer implementation that would read the JVM arguments to find out which features need to be executed and then based the list of features retrieved, it retrieves this custom annotation to find out to what feature does a test method belong to, and if it's not part of the current feature, it gets disabled.
- You build a custom reporter that also reports all the disabled tests as "Not applicable" tests.